# JavaScript event handling for load

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am following [this](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Handling_events_with_JavaScript#The_evolution_of_events) link to learn about basic JavaScript but for some strange reason this little piece of code does not seem to be playing nice with me. Any suggestions on why I am not getting the alerts would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Creeper</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            addEvent(window, "load", sayHi);
            function sayHi(){
                alert("jekyl");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" title="click me", id="my-link">Click Me!</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/10/add-event/ Here is implementation of `addEvent` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

addEvent isn't a method implemented in `window`. The article you're following refers to it, but is assuming you've loaded an implementation first, which you haven't done in the code you posted. You can try Dean Edwards implementation (link in the comments above) or try this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            alert("jekyl");
        }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use Event Listeners:

```
if (window.addEventListener){
    window.addEventListener('load', sayHi, false); // All browsers except IE
} else if (window.attachEvent && !window.opera){
    window.attachEvent('onload', sayHi); // IE
}

function sayHi(){
    alert("jekyl");
}
```